# Async NullRefrenceException from Html Agility Pack's LoadFromWebAsync

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, nullreferenceexception, blazor-server-side

I'm using Html Agility Pack to get meta tags from URLs. I was using `HtmlWeb`'s `Load`, but I found it to be taking too long and thought that I could probably speed up performance using an async method instead. However, when I tried to use `LoadFromWebAsync` I get a NullReferenceException.

Using `Load`

```cs
public static MetaTags GetMetaData(string url)
{
    // This works 
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    var document = webGet.Load(url);
    var metaTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta");
    MetaTags metaInfo = new MetaTags(url);
    //more code
}
```

Using `LoadFromWebAsync`

```cs
public static async Task<MetaTags> GetMetaData(string url)
{
    // This doesn't work 
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    var document = await webGet.LoadFromWebAsync(url); //breaks here
    var metaTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta");
    MetaTags metaInfo = new MetaTags(url);
    //more code
}
```

I am using this method to get the url data to pass to a `NewsCard` component which I attempt to do like:

```cs
<p
@news.Title
</p>

@code {
    public MetaTags news { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
            news = await MetaScraper.GetMetaData(" https://www.denverpost.com/2020/10/03/president-trump-fight-against-covid-19-update/");
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error, and what can I do to fix it?

Edit:
Im not sure what is null, I'm working in Blazor and when it breaks it exits out to _Host.cshtml on this line which existed since I created the project:
. I think it might have something to do with me attempting to load the component before it has anything to fill.

Stack Trace:

```
ThinBlueLieB.Components.NewsCard.<BuildRenderTree>b__0_0(RenderTreeBuilder __builder2)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(int sequence, RenderFragment fragment)
Syncfusion.Blazor.Cards.SfCard.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessPendingRender()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(int componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToPendingTasks(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(int componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.CreateInitialRenderAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext+<>c__11<TResult>+<<InvokeAsync>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StaticComponentRenderer.PrerenderComponentAsync(ParameterView parameters, HttpContext httpContext, Type componentType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.PrerenderedServerComponentAsync(HttpContext context, ServerComponentInvocationSequence invocationId, Type type, ParameterView parametersCollection)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(ViewContext viewContext, Type componentType, RenderMode renderMode, object parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ComponentTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
ThinBlueLieB.Pages.Pages__Host.<ExecuteAsync>b__17_1() in _Host.cshtml
+
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />        
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
ThinBlueLieB.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync() in _Host.cshtml
+
    Layout = null;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware.ExecuteWithFilter(IHttpSocketAdapter injectScriptSocket, string requestId, HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: What *exactly* is breaking? In this case, what is null?

Comment: I tried the async method, and it works fine up to this line: var metaTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta");    // It contains a HtmlNodeCollection which you can process further

Comment: Im not sure what is null, I'm working in Blazor and when it breaks it exits out to _Host.cshtml on this line: ```<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />```

Comment: `ServerPrerendered` is for Blazor Server, which means you *can* debug your application and use breakpoints. You can also use exception handling and logging to see where the exception was thrown. The full exception text contains the location where the exception was thrown and a stack trace showing the calls that led to it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've updated my question to include the stack trace, but it I don't understand it well enough for it to point to a line of code that is causing the issue. I can't hit any breakpoints after the ```await ...``` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was attempting to show the data before it was loaded. This was because I was using async but not providing something to show while it was awaiting a result. It can be fixed by doing:

```cs
if (news.HasData == false) {
    <p>Loading</p>
}
else{
    <p>
    @news.Title
    </p>
}
@code {
    public MetaTags news { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        news = new MetaTags(newsUrl); //initialized with HasData = false
        news = await MetaScraper.GetMetaData(newsUrl); //Filling out with data later. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please accept your answer so the issue can show  as answered

Comment: I can't, you have you wait 24 hours before accepting an answer you posted to your own question